# How to place center of a view inside FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have a `FrameLayout` which already holds a child view, and I know its width and height in pixels. I want to programmatically add a new view so that its center is at the specific point of the frame layout. Size of the view is not known and its `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` is set to `WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Say you want to position a `TextView` in the middle of a `FrameLayout`.

```
TextView text = (TextView)frame.findViewById(R.id.text);
FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame1);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Now add your `TextView` to your `FrameLayout` and set gravity to center

```
frame.addView(text);
params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
```

I haven't tried it but I think it should work.

Comment: What if I want to put center of the TextView at specific position in FrameLayout? Say I want to put it to position = (100, 50).

Comment: Dumb question: so now I have this variable called "params" that has the layout I want. What do I need to call in FrameLayout so that these parameters are actually being used?

Comment: Answer to my question is: 
text.setLayoutParams(params); // call after adding to FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

### In KOTLIN

```
 viewToADD?.layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams
                   (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).
                    apply {gravity = Gravity.CENTER and Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL}

  frameLayout.addView(viewToADD)
```